# explanation of "-" and "+" in `trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef`

Tags: scala

What are the purposes and definitions of "-" and "+" used for the input and return types in the trait signature such as `trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef`

Can someone suggest exact location in spec to read about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-" is contravariant "+" is covariant

You can read subtyping in this blog http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/

Also, coursera course functional programming of scala talks about it as well.

"-" let you use subclass of T, so it is restricted for the input, "+" let you return supertype of T, so it is general for the output.

```
class SuperBase

class Base extends SuperBase

class SubBase extends Base

val add: Function1[Base, Base] = { base =>
  new SubBase //ignore this
}

add(new SubBase) //ok
add(new SuperBase) //compilation fail

val result: SuperBase = add(new SubBase) //ok
val result: SubBase = add(new SubBase) //compilation fail
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are variance and covariance annotations which are used to specify how the subtype relationship works for polymorphic types. For example `List[+A]` indicates that the lists are covariant by its content: if you have a type `Dog` which is a subtype of `Animal` then the type `List[Dog]` will be a subtype of `List[Animal]`. In funny symbols: If you have types `A<:B` and you have defined a type `X[+T]` with a covariant type parameter `T` then `X[A]<:X[B]`. The "-" is used for contravariance and I find it hard to give an example of its use: in general if `A<:B` and you have a type `X[-T]` then `X[B] <: X[A]`. You may want to see the coursera's course in programming languages which I think explains this and also why functions are contravariant in its arguments and covariant in its results.